# In this code i want to refresh my custom listview on save button click

Tags: java, android

Thing which i want in my code is listed below.

1. this method is not refreshing listview on button click.

   ```
   public synchronized void refresAdapter(ArrayList<ManageCuisineHelper> dataitems) {

       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you are not updating the latest data in the refreshAdapter method of your Adapter class. Change the method body like below and that should work for you.

```
public synchronized void refresAdapter(ArrayList<ManageCuisineHelper> dataitems) {
        if(this.list_data != null) {
          this.list_data.clear();
          this.list_data = dataitems;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution earlier but it was not applicable for my code and I come up with above solution. Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

I brainstormed the solution as below.

I added this code on button click event.

```
arrayList1.clear();
cuisineDisplayData();
```

Comment: You didn't specify `arrayList1` and `cuisineDisplayData()` in the thread